# Can I set render settings by individual scenes?

Tags: scene

I have a .blend file with two scenes in it.

Can I set different *Properties panel > Render tab* settings (dimensions, frame rate, etc.) for different scenes in the same .blend file?

Thanks.

Comment: what did you try before asking this question?

Comment: When i was in my blender file i was thinking that the render setting was linked between the two scene, but it was a mistake

Comment: I would like to encourage you to try things first and take your time to read through the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/), then ask questions if you fail hard, we are here to help with failing :) Reading through the wiki is great because you will encounter new things that you didn't think of before.

Comment: @GabrielS ah, since you *didn't* specify that you were getting any undesirable behavior, I couldn't advise you on what you were doing wrong, I only could tell you what to do. But it is as zeffii says, you are encouraged to try first and search around before asking.

Comment: it's ok i was try but it was a mistake.
i was thinking that blender don't have multiple render settings.
(sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, make sure when creating a new scene to choose *New* for a fresh default scene or *Full Copy* to make a copy of your current one.

**Any changes you make to the settings in either scene will stay unique to that scene.**

As per the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Scenes), the three options when creating a new scene that I think you should pay attention to are:

> **New**
>   Creates an empty Scene. In the new Scene, the Render Settings are set to the default values.
>
> **Copy Settings**
>   Creates an empty Scene like the previous option but also copies the Render Settings from the original Scene into the new
>   one.
>
> **Full Copy**  Is the deepest form of copying available. Nothing is shared. This option creates a fully independent Scene with copies of
>   the currently selected Scene's contents. Every Object in the original
>   Scene is duplicated, and a duplicate, private copy of its ObData is
>   made as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I thought it was not the case in my two separate scene. Now it works fine