# Each camera may always keep the same resolution?

Tags: camera

I have an object with different cameras that these have different resolutions, but every time I make a render, the camera has changed the resolution of the previous camera, is it possible that this does not change the resolution?

thanks

Comment: See [this answer.](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3238/12)

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, the answer is **no**.

The resolution is a global property used by all camera objects in the scene.

One way to work around this is to create a new scene:

1. Create a new scene with *Link Objects* in *Info > Header* by pressing the **+** button:

   [image]

   This will make copy the current scene into new one and make object mesh data and transforms linked from one scene to another, so if you move or edit an object in one scene, the corresponding object in another scene will move to match it.
2. Set the other camera as active in the new scene (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>)
3. Change the resolution in the new scene.
4. To render, select the scene which has the active camera and resolution you want and press <kbd>F12</kbd>

Note that it is probably simpler and easier to set the resolution manually when you render.

Comment: I think you're right; though a script that temp replaces the render resolution with values from a custom property on the camera would be quite useful and probably strhightforward.