# Camera with different properties

Tags: rendering, camera

In this 3d model space multiple camera are placed.[image]

One camera is desired for portrait shot (1200 X 1800 pixels)while other in landscape (1800 X 1200 pixels) shot.
[image]
[image]

But in blender when one camera setting is changed to the landscape proportion the other automatically changes to landscape (which is not desired).

However there is some workaround that to change the orientation of second camera so that other camera remains undisturbed (but this is annoying to look at).
Is there any proper method to resolve the Orientation Issue.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5511/599

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, you set the resolution to the "scene render properties", not "camera properties", and it makes sense, eg: if you animate a scene with two cameras, one landscape and the other portrait, and during the animation you switch the camera, how should the animation video be rendered...?

You can use a scene copy, though. Every scene has its own "scene render properties", and you can use Scene 1 render 1200 X 1800  and Scene 2 1800 X 1200. But you'll need to render them separately, I guess.