# How do I render scenes with different resolution and aspect ratios in a composition?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, multiresolution

I want to make some renders for a pepper's ghost hologram with three sides. So I render with my Object and Cameras linked together in different Scenes.
In a different Scene I composite the Scenes so that Suzanne is in the right place with the right size. The render of the composition should have a 1920 x 1080 resolution. BUT the Rendering of the Scenes should happen in a 430 x 430 resolution because that takes WAY less time.

So in the Picture you can hopefully see what I mean.
[image: Screenshot of the Problem]

Somehow I can't get it to work. My Scenes always render in the full resolution of the composition. Takes 1:27 per Frame instead of 00:06 with the lower resolution to render the three scenes.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3237/1245

Comment: Wow, I've never tried this before. The master scene resets all feeder scene dimensions. I'm not sure why, and the VSE OpenGL preview shows the right dimensions. I guess you'll have to prerender.